# Nginx - different domains on same path root

Tags: nginx

I have two domains (`domain1.com`and `domain2.us`) for WPML. Both should have the same root (`/var/www/html`), but my configuration don't work (simplified):

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
  root /var/www/html;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name domain2.us www.domain2.us;
  root /var/www/html;
  ...
}
```

Although `domain1.com` does show the files of the folder, `domain2.us` doesn't. How is the alternative (both domains have also a SSL certificate)?

Comment: please explain what `don't work` entails

Comment: `domain2.us` shows `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Comment: How `/` is resolved will depend on the rest of the configuration. 403 may be the correct response..

Comment: But then why does `domain1.com` shows the right content?